# Data loader .csv files

Tags: data-loader

How to map the fields in data loader from .csv file? what does the .csv file contains? can anyone explain with an example

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? It's easier to see it in action than to read the documentation... Try exporting some data from the object you're interested in, examine the results file, change something, upload it back as update/upsert operation?

Comment: In the SFDC help, see [Defining Field Mappings](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=defining_field_mappings.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, have a look at the [Data Loader Guide (pdf)](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf) and [Data Loader Video](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader_Video).

> what does the .csv file contains?

Values separated by columns that you wish to map to a Salesforce objects field.

One way to use the dataloader is to create a field mapping from the columns in your CSV to the fields of a Salesforce object.

Have a look at Chapter 3: Using Data Loader in the PDF. In particular *Inserting, Updating, or Deleting Data Using Data Loader* on pg 12.